# Storing and recalling output from strategies in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am posting my query again for the same issue I am facing. I have tried NetLogo model library, table command and all other options in my domain. I am still unable to solve the problem.
Here is my problem; I want turtles to be rational and evaluate strategies with best output and adapt the one with highest output with upcoming time period. It is as farmers evaluate their water use behavior and learn from past and adapt accordingly. In the codes I have tried writing it as farmers have 3 strategies which give them different yield. In go farmer will evaluate and follow the strategy with maximum yield. I am unable to call and follow the strategy with maximum yield.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks
Here are the codes:

```
Globals [ surface-water  groundwater  maximum-yield water-demand  water-used ]
Turtles-own [strategies strategy memory land groundwater-use surfacewater-use yield ]
to setup
  clear-all
  let memory-length 5
  ;let strategies ["use-gw" "use-sw" "50G-50s" "70G-25S" "25G-70S"]
  crt 10 [ ;set yield 0
    set memory n-values memory-length [-1]
  set surface-water 10
  set maximum-yield 60
  set groundwater 20
  set water-demand 17
  set land random 5 + 3

     strategy-1
     strategy-2
    strategy-3
    ;best-strategy
    let no-strategies [ "strategy-1"  "strategy-2" "strategy-3"]
    set strategy n-values 2 [one-of no-strategies]
    ]
    reset-ticks
end
  to strategy-1
  set surfacewater-use water-demand - surface-water
  if surface-water < 0 [ set surface-water 0]
  let excess-demand water-demand - surface-water
  set groundwater-use  excess-demand - groundwater
  set yield 100 * surfacewater-use / water-demand + 70 * groundwater-use / water-demand
end
to
strategy-2
   set surfacewater-use surface-water - 0.5 * water-demand
  if surface-water < 0 [ set surface-water 0]
   set groundwater-use groundwater -  0.5 * water-demand
  set yield 100 * surfacewater-use / water-demand + 70 * groundwater-use / water-demand
end
to
strategy-3
  set yield 70  
end

to go
  tick
  ask turtles
  [set yield run-result strategy
    ;foreach strategy run
    set memory fput output but-last memory]

ask turtles [
  show memory
  show item 0 memory
  show item 1 memory
  show item 2 memory
  show item 3 memory
    show item 4 memory]
  end

to-report output
  report yield
 end
```

Comment: The reason you are not getting an answer is that the question is not specific enough. Is it giving an error message (and if so, what message and which line) or doing the wrong behaviour (what is it doing instead)? Don't give us irrelevant code either, what is the exact problem and show the code that is not working.

Comment: I see Jenb. I will say that